# Atheros 9462 in Ubuntu 16.04 not cornnecting to 5ghz Wi-Fi

Tags: 16.04, wireless

My Wi-fi worked just fine (though, admittedly, quite slowly as I am in an apartment complex with everyone on 2.4Ghz and a loss of 20+Mbps from the router to my bedroom, which is ridiculous) when it was on 2.4Ghz. For speed reasons, I'm trying to get it on 5Ghz, but it seems impossible.

Everything else in the house works, but in Ubuntu, now that I've change the Network to 5Ghz, my SID moved from the normal drop-down to inside the 'Connect to a Hidden...'. And when I try to connect, it fails every. single. time. No connection whatsoever.

I don't understand why.

I've done all of these so-called 'fixes' for similar issues, but nothing is working:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential  
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source  
sudo rfkil unblock all  
echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf**
```

And I KNOW this card is capable of 5Ghz.

```
$ iwlist wlp4s0 freq
wlp4s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :  
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz  
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz  
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz  
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz  
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz   
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz  
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz   
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz  
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz  
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz  
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz  
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz  
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz  
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz  
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz  
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz  
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz  
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz  
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz  
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz  
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz  
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz  
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz  
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz  
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz  
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz  
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz  
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz  
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz   
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz  
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz  
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz  
          Current Frequency=2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

And `lshw` pulls up:

```
  *-network
                description: Wireless interface  
                product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter  
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros  
                physical id: 0  
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0  
                logical name: wlp4s0  
                version: 01  
                serial: 40:e2:30:ad:e9:79  
                width: 64 bits  
                clock: 33MHz  
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless  
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=172.20.20.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11  
                resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
```

So....yeah. Any help would be great. I've got an Asus N551J with an Atheros AR9462 card.

```
$ uname -a
Linux whitt-N551JQ 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It even seems to be using the right driver (which is what I thought would be incorrect). Any other ideas? Oh, yeah; I also disabled (or selected 'Ignore') in the IPV6 settings. I deleted the saved connection as well, and when I did, the Network disappeared completely, and I could not even attempt to reconnect unless I added a hidden network. For some reason, it's like my Wi-fi adapter can't even see the 5Ghz Network.

Any ideas? Seriously. I don't know what else to do. I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't know how the secure boot thing works, so when it told me to make a password after trying to install restricted drivers: **sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source**, I did so, but I did NOT hit 'any' key when the MOK blue screen came up, because I didn't know what it was. Later, I thought maybe that was the problem, and I tried **sudo apt-get autoremove bcmwl-kernel-source**, followed by the install again, but it did not tell me to make a password for Secure Boot again, so....I messed something up by NOT clicking on something I didn't understand?!  (≧ _≦╬) ... (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: UPDATE: I have turned off Secure Boot (finally). Then, I purged the **bcmwl-kernel-source** and tried to reinstall. I got this at the end: "Building initial module for 4.10.0-28-generic..ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'...Error! Bad return status for module build...modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory...
deferring update...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915"   Are the restricted drivers allowed now or not?

Comment: To the close voters: see the answer OP has posted.

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` is only for Broadcom wireless devices. It can't be useful with Atheros.

Answer (score 1):

I was so frustrated, I actually went and asked ASUS Customer Support, who said:

> I regret to inform you that the device does not have the capability to
>   connect to a 5.0 GHz network. The unit is limited to the 2.4 GHz
>   networks.

So, yeah. Sorry for this question, I guess. But I'm still not sure why `iwlist xxxx freq` called up ALL The card's abilities and got me so hopeful. You'd think the response might have been affected by ASUS's configuration of the card. But, well, if they only managed it at driver level, I suppose it makes sense.